# Frame wont display my panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am having trouble displaying my panel class on the frame class the i created. here are my panel and my frame

```
public class PasswordCheckerPanel extends JPanel 
{
    private String string;
    private JButton B1, B2, B3;
    private JLabel Rules, L1, L2, L3, Type, Retype;
    private JTextField TF1, TF2;
    private ArrayList<String> AR1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> AR2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private JFileChooser Input, Output;


    public PasswordCheckerPanel()
    {
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JPanel Panel1 = new JPanel();
        TitledBorder Titled1 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Password Checker Rules");
        Rules = new JLabel();
        Rules.setText("Use the following rules when creating your passwords");
        L1= new JLabel();
        L1.setText("1. Length must be greater than 6.");
        L2 = new JLabel();
        L2.setText("2. Must contain atleast one alpha character");
        L3 = new JLabel();
        L3.setText("3. Must contain atleast one numeric character");
        Panel1.setBorder(Titled1);
        Panel1.add(Rules);
        Panel1.add(L1);
        Panel1.add(L2);
        Panel1.add(L3);
        add(Panel1);

        JPanel Panel2 = new JPanel();
        Type = new JLabel();
        Type.setText("Password: ");
        Retype = new JLabel();
        Retype.setText("Re-Type Password: ");
        TF1 = new JTextField(20);
        TF2 = new JTextField(20);
        Panel2.add(Type);
        Panel2.add(TF1);
        Panel2.add(Retype);
        Panel2.add(TF2);

        add(Panel2);

        JPanel Panel3 = new JPanel();
        B1.setMnemonic('c');
        B1.setText("Check Password");
        B1.setToolTipText("Check Password");
        B1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        B2.setMnemonic('f');
        B2.setText("Check Password in File");
        B2.setToolTipText("Check Password in File");
        B2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        B3.setMnemonic('e');
        B3.setText("Exit");
        B3.setToolTipText("Exit");
        B3.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        Panel3.add(B1);
        Panel3.add(B2);
        Panel3.add(B3);

        add(Panel3);


    }

}
```

Here is my frame

```
public class PasswordCheckerFrame extends JFrame
{
    private PasswordCheckerPanel Panel = new PasswordCheckerPanel(); // Creates a PasswordCheckerPanel object

    public PasswordCheckerFrame() // PasswordCheckerFrame Constructor
    {

            JFrame WindowBox = new JFrame(); // Creates a new JFrame

            WindowBox.setTitle("Password Checker"); // sets JFrame title
            WindowBox.setSize(500, 500); // sets JFrame size
            WindowBox.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // sets the operation as to what happens when you close the gui
            WindowBox.add(Panel); // adds the Panel to the JFrame
            WindowBox.pack(); // Packs for size refitting
            WindowBox.setVisible(true); // sets visibility of the Frame

        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            new PasswordCheckerFrame(); // creates an instance of the PasswordCheckerFrame class
        }

    }
```

Could you point to any errors i might have made? I keep getting a J Unit test verison something something so really having trouble finding out what i am doing wrong. is it the code or something else?

Answer (score 0):

First of all use proper Java variable naming conventions. Variable names DO NOT start with an upper cased character. Only class names start with an upper cased character, so your code is confusing to read. It looks like you are invoking static methods of a class.

Now, for your problem:

```
private JButton B1, B2, B3;
```

You never create your buttons so those variables are null.

Edit:

I just added 3 lines of code to you posted code (and removed the action listeners) and the code worked fine, so I'm not sure what you are doing.

```
B1 = new JButton("B1"); // added the creation of the button   
B1.setMnemonic('c');
```

Comment: ah sorry about the convention things. Thank you for your help.

Comment: i did the things you reccomended, yet its still not displaying my panel on the window Frame, hell a windowFrame isnt even showing up, it keeps getting terminated.

Comment: @user1873746, see edit. Post an SSCCE if you still have problems.